# Unable to set numeric DataMapper field to blank value

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I can't seem to find any way to successfully set a decimal field to no value from a form, since the form is returning an empty string. Here's a super-simple test case that manually sets the field to `''`

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-mysql-adapter'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper.setup(:default, 'mysql://localhost/test')

class Product
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial

  property :list_price, Decimal
end

DataMapper.finalize

DataMapper.auto_migrate!

p = Product.new
puts p.save   #=> true

p = Product.new(:list_price => '')
puts p.save   #=> false

p  = Product.new(:list_price => nil)
puts p.save   #=> true
```

As you can see, the `list_price` field will happily save when it's not set, or when it's set to nil. However, when I use a blank string, it won't save at all -- it's seemingly not being typecast.

It seems like I must be missing something obvious here, since this is a pretty basic use-case for an ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own setter method for the property to check its type. See the section "Over-riding Accessors" on the [Datamapper properties documentation page](http://datamapper.org/docs/properties.html).

Adding:

```
def list_price=(new_price)
  new_price = nil if new_price == ''
  super
end
```

to your `Product` class will cause any empty string being set as the value of `list_price` to be converted to nil, and allow the resource to be saved.

Comment: While this would solve the problem, it seems absurd to have to do it manually. Isn't this why we have ORMs?

Comment: @Emily I found this related issue: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/issues/41. "...we decided it’s not DataMapper’s responsibility to typecast empty strings to nils". They concede that it would be useful for webapps though.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I hadn't turned that up in my searches. Sadly, it doesn't seem to have actually made it into dm-rails as suggested in the thread. I ended up monkey-patching `typecast` to support it.

Comment: @Emily: [Here](https://github.com/FeeJai/dm-core/commit/f2d2c1333b63788963087713984b428c28488733) is a patch for DataMapper that adds an option `DataMapper::Model.cast_empty_strings_to_nil = true` which will enable this behaviour without changing every setter manually. I'm going to create a pull request and merge this into mainline as soon as I have tests.